# Centring 2 buttons inside a div in bootsrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

First of all hi and thanks for your time!
I have a problem that I can't solve with bootsrap, I'm trying to center 2 buttons inside a div, in this code the buttons are aligned left, how can I center them?
Here is my code:

```
<div class="align-self-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"> BTN1</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">BTN2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `.text-center` instead of `.align-self-center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use text-center class provided by bootstrap to align your buttons.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">BTN1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">BTN2</button>
</div>
```

The text-center class is basically doing -

```
text-align:center;
```

P.S. Not sure what **.align-self-center** is doing here

Suggestion - I see that you are using bootstrap 4. You can also use the class "btn-group" if it meets your requirements.
[Click here to go to bootstrap 4 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/)